# Am I allowed to transport a bycicle on the train in The Netherlands and Belgium?

Tags: trains, bicycles, netherlands, belgium

I am planning to travel through the Netherlands / Belgium and visit several cities. The most confortable/fast way seems to be the train, but for the city visit and nearby places the bicycle is ideal. Am I allowed to travel with a Bicycle in the train?

Comment: Would you consider renting?

Comment: That depends on the renting conditions. If competitive,  in this case, yes!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Belgium and in the Netherlands you can take your bicycle on the train. Some restrictions may apply.

In Belgium, the conductor will show you the place where you can store the bicycle. It costs [5 EUR per journey](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/tickets/bike-trip.aspx), or [8 EUR per day](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/tickets/bike-day.aspx). Folding bicycles are carried for free. You are advised to avoid trains during the peak hours, although it is not strictly forbidden.

In the Netherlands you can take your bicycle with you on the train during off-peak hours. Peak hours are weekdays from 06:30 to 09:00 and from 16:30 to 18:00. This restriction does not apply at weekends, on public holidays or in July and August. Bicycles must be placed in the special bicycle area on the train. You will recognise this area by the sticker on the outside of the train. As in Belgium, you need to pay a supplement and folding bicycles are carried for free. The price for the supplement is [6 EUR per day](http://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/arrange-and-buy/tickets-and-passes/ticket-and-pass-types), irrespective of the journey.

Comment: mind that at least in the Netherlands not all trains have bicycle storage areas.

Comment: In the Netherlands, if there is no bicycle storage area you can usually stow it where it fits (outside rushhour most trains have space), you'd just have to watch it a bit more closely during your journey in case it is in the way.

Comment: If you travel between Brussels and the Netherlands, you can also take your bicycle on the Intercity Brussels train, costs 12€. https://www.nsinternational.nl/en/before-you-go/taking-your-bicycle-with-you 

In Belgium, there are two types of trains.:
"Old types" have somewhere in the middle or the end a special wagoon, which has a compartment, and ONLY the conductor can open it. So you need to meet him/her first, so they open it for you. To get off, you need to ask them again to open it. It can store about 4-5 bikes only.
"New types", have a dedicated bike area, with a bicycle logo outside.